# running a python script in atom

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, atom-editor, jupyter-irkernel

I have been using `atom 1.36.1` to run `python3` (3.7.3) code

I suddenly got the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "main", mod_spec) 
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in from ipykernel import kernelapp as app File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/init.py", line 2, in from .connect import * 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/init.py", line 54, in from .core.application import Application 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 18, in import logging
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/init.py", line 28, in from string import Template ImportError: cannot import name 'Template' from 'string' (/Users/mymac/Downloads/string.py)
```

This is the content of the jupyter kernel json file:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/bin/python3",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "Python 3",
 "language": "python"
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem: I had created a file `string.py` (in `/Users/mymac/Downloads/string.py`) which was named the same as another file used by the the file `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/init.py`

I deleted this `string.py` and this solved the problem